# my ADB manager dosen't show any Device in the List

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion, mobile-development

I use Ubuntu 16.0 and Android studio 2.1.2
I created some of a virtual device in AVD manager , and also I'm run Genymotion as a virtual device ,
but when I'm open ADB manager I can't see any device at list !!

[image]

Comment: than create new emulator ..............

Comment: What is your question? Shell we sympathize or is there anything else we can do for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually occurs when your adb daemon is not running. So you need to restart it or just start.

Do do this you can try next two commands in terminal:

```
adb stop-server
adb start-server
```

Comment: thank you for your response :
 i try it from command line and from Android monitor by restarting adb ,
but it is still doesn't working .

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to vote for my answer if it helped you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can connect via adb to Genymotion with

```
adb connect <your ip>
```

Where your ip you can find on **Genymotion Virtual Device Manager**

Comment: but I can't find my genymotion IP address in Virtual Box  manager ?

Comment: You can find the ip under setting of android -> Wifi -> Advanced...
In other way you can install plugin for Eclipse/Android Studio of genymotion for debugin directly by the IDE: https://docs.genymotion.com/Content/Home.htm Here some guides..
**https://docs.genymotion.com/pdf/PDF_Plugin_for_Eclipse/Plugin-for-Eclipse-1.0.6-Guide.pdf** This one is for installing plugin for Eclipse.
**https://docs.genymotion.com/pdf/PDF_Plugin_for_Android_Studio/Plugin-for-Android-Studio-1.0.7-Guide.pdf** This one is for installing plugin for Android Studio.